# Laravel Queued Job, Execute it before its execution time

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I created a Laravel job to be executed on a specific date and time (e.g., tomorrow). I want to add a manual button that overrides the time and executes that queued job before its set execution time. 
Clicking the button creates an ajax call and send a job ID to the server. This then leads to the job being executed today instead of tomorrow.

We can manually retry failed jobs using the following command:
`php artisan queue:retry JOBIDHERE`

I am not sure what to use for executing a queued job.

I can get the job ID, but I do not know if it is possible to execute the Laravel Job before its set execution time.

I searched on Google but did not found anyone with such problem and solution.

I am using Laravel Ver 5.8.
Using Mysql 5.7

---

**Update:**

Following is the payload for the queued Job.

I tried to use Json Decode and decoded it, but I am not sure if can update the command for that queue so that I can update the date and time for the queue and save it back to the queued job record.

```
{"displayName":"App\\Jobs\\Payway\\UpdateCustomerInvestment","job":"Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call","maxTries":null,"delay":null,"timeout":null,"timeoutAt":null,"data":{"commandName":"App\\Jobs\\Payway\\UpdateCustomerInvestment","command":"O:40:\"App\\Jobs\\Payway\\UpdateCustomerInvestment\":17:{s:57:\"\u0000App\\Jobs\\Payway\\UpdateCustomerInvestment\u0000transactionType\";s:7:\"payment\";s:57:\"\u0000App\\Jobs\\Payway\\UpdateCustomerInvestment\u0000principalAmount\";d:9999;s:56:\"\u0000App\\Jobs\\Payway\\UpdateCustomerInvestment\u0000customerNumber\";s:4:\"BR-2\";s:50:\"\u0000App\\Jobs\\Payway\\UpdateCustomerInvestment\u0000currency\";s:3:\"aud\";s:58:\"\u0000App\\Jobs\\Payway\\UpdateCustomerInvestment\u0000singleUseTokenID\";N;s:55:\"\u0000App\\Jobs\\Payway\\UpdateCustomerInvestment\u0000payway_helper\";O:29:\"App\\Http\\Helpers\\PaywayHelper\":0:{}s:54:\"\u0000App\\Jobs\\Payway\\UpdateCustomerInvestment\u0000impodenceKey\";s:36:\"afedfc34-d08e-4831-a4aa-29de930d6b98\";s:49:\"\u0000App\\Jobs\\Payway\\UpdateCustomerInvestment\u0000headers\";a:0:{}s:60:\"\u0000App\\Jobs\\Payway\\UpdateCustomerInvestment\u0000localInvestmentObj\";O:45:\"Illuminate\\Contracts\\Database\\ModelIdentifier\":4:{s:5:\"class\";s:33:\"App\\Models\\Investment\\Investments\";s:2:\"id\";i:374;s:9:\"relations\";a:2:{i:0;s:8:\"investor\";i:1;s:13:\"investor.user\";}s:10:\"connection\";s:5:\"mysql\";}s:54:\"\u0000App\\Jobs\\Payway\\UpdateCustomerInvestment\u0000paywayTotals\";O:45:\"Illuminate\\Contracts\\Database\\ModelIdentifier\":4:{s:5:\"class\";s:38:\"App\\Models\\Banking\\Payway\\PaywayTotals\";s:2:\"id\";i:1;s:9:\"relations\";a:0:{}s:10:\"connection\";s:5:\"mysql\";}s:6:\"\u0000*\u0000job\";N;s:10:\"connection\";N;s:5:\"queue\";s:6:\"payway\";s:15:\"chainConnection\";N;s:10:\"chainQueue\";N;s:5:\"delay\";O:13:\"Carbon\\Carbon\":3:{s:4:\"date\";s:26:\"2019-11-12 23:35:22.752222\";s:13:\"timezone_type\";i:3;s:8:\"timezone\";s:16:\"Australia\/Sydney\";}s:7:\"chained\";a:0:{}}"}}
```

---

**Update 2:**

When I deserialized the payload Command, I got the following information.

[image]

So I am trying to update that delay date, hopefully it will work.

But from the answer of "Julian Stark", I may have to update the available_at as well.

My theory is when the queue runs, it will look for jobs based on `available_at`. However, when the job is executing and it it has a delay, it might not execute at that specific time. This theory is yet to be tested.

I will update both of these dateTimes and check if everything works smoothly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In a similar use case, I just updated the jobs `available_at` time, so the `queue:listen` command executes the job as soon as possible.

```
DB::table('jobs')->where('id', $jobId)->update(['available_at' => time()]);
```

I don't know if this is the correct way to do it, but it worked for me

Comment: Updated my question with new findings. Please check those out.
Thankyou for mentioning about the available_at.

Comment: I tested my example in laravel 5.8 without modifying the `payload` delay and the job executes, so your theory mentioned in Update 2 is wrong

Comment: I'd change `time()` to `DB::raw('NOW()')` just to be sure.

Answer (score 5):

To achieve this, all you have to do is first decode your payload which will be

```
{
   "displayName":"App\\Jobs\\Payway\\UpdateCustomerInvestment",
   "job":"Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call",
   "maxTries":null,
   "delay":null,
   "timeout":null,
   "timeoutAt":null,
   "data":{
      "commandName":"App\\Jobs\\Payway\\UpdateCustomerInvestment",
      "command":"O:40:\"App\\Jobs\\Payway\\UpdateCustomerInvestment\":17:{s:57:\"\u0000App\\Jobs\\Payway\\UpdateCustomerInvestment\u0000transactionType\";s:7:\"payment\";s:57:\"\u0000App\\Jobs\\Payway\\UpdateCustomerInvestment\u0000principalAmount\";d:9999;s:56:\"\u0000App\\Jobs\\Payway\\UpdateCustomerInvestment\u0000customerNumber\";s:4:\"BR-2\";s:50:\"\u0000App\\Jobs\\Payway\\UpdateCustomerInvestment\u0000currency\";s:3:\"aud\";s:58:\"\u0000App\\Jobs\\Payway\\UpdateCustomerInvestment\u0000singleUseTokenID\";N;s:55:\"\u0000App\\Jobs\\Payway\\UpdateCustomerInvestment\u0000payway_helper\";O:29:\"App\\Http\\Helpers\\PaywayHelper\":0:{}s:54:\"\u0000App\\Jobs\\Payway\\UpdateCustomerInvestment\u0000impodenceKey\";s:36:\"afedfc34-d08e-4831-a4aa-29de930d6b98\";s:49:\"\u0000App\\Jobs\\Payway\\UpdateCustomerInvestment\u0000headers\";a:0:{}s:60:\"\u0000App\\Jobs\\Payway\\UpdateCustomerInvestment\u0000localInvestmentObj\";O:45:\"Illuminate\\Contracts\\Database\\ModelIdentifier\":4:{s:5:\"class\";s:33:\"App\\Models\\Investment\\Investments\";s:2:\"id\";i:374;s:9:\"relations\";a:2:{i:0;s:8:\"investor\";i:1;s:13:\"investor.user\";}s:10:\"connection\";s:5:\"mysql\";}s:54:\"\u0000App\\Jobs\\Payway\\UpdateCustomerInvestment\u0000paywayTotals\";O:45:\"Illuminate\\Contracts\\Database\\ModelIdentifier\":4:{s:5:\"class\";s:38:\"App\\Models\\Banking\\Payway\\PaywayTotals\";s:2:\"id\";i:1;s:9:\"relations\";a:0:{}s:10:\"connection\";s:5:\"mysql\";}s:6:\"\u0000*\u0000job\";N;s:10:\"connection\";N;s:5:\"queue\";s:6:\"payway\";s:15:\"chainConnection\";N;s:10:\"chainQueue\";N;s:5:\"delay\";O:13:\"Carbon\\Carbon\":3:{s:4:\"date\";s:26:\"2019-11-12 23:35:22.752222\";s:13:\"timezone_type\";i:3;s:8:\"timezone\";s:16:\"Australia\/Sydney\";}s:7:\"chained\";a:0:{}}"
   }
}
```

When you have decoded your payload, you'll see the **"command"** is serialized, so next you've to unserialize **"command"**.

```
[delay] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-11-12 23:35:22.752222
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => Australia/Sydney
        )
```

After that, you can then update the date under the **delay** node and either using Carbon or PHP date, update the date as per your need.
After doing that, you just need to serialize the **"command"** node again and then `json_encode` the whole payload and save it.

You'll also need to follow @Julian Stark's answer as well, that is, modify the `available_at` of that job.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I followed the same process already and updated both dates. Already Working flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

updating the time of queued job will be the bad practice instead of that you can flush the scheduled job and run dispatch now function.

Comment: That can also work.
Thou i am not sure why the other method is a bad practice? Both methods seems fine to me, Updating the date directly or deleting existing and creating job again.
But i wanted to look how we can update the date/time of existing job.